NextJS 14: Error from defining an inline "use server" annotated Server Action in Learn NextJS' Ch 15: Adding Authentication section
For Learn NextJS's Chapter 15: Adding Authentication, the provided implementation for the sign out button leads to the following error.
Error: 
  × It is not allowed to define inline "use server" annotated Server Actions in Client Components.
  │ To use Server Actions in a Client Component, you can either export them from a separate file with "use server" at the top, or pass them down through props from a Server Component.
  │ 
  │ Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/server-actions#with-client-components
  │ 
    ╭─[/Users/peckyang/Dropbox/12 Code/NextJS/NextJS Dashboard/nextjs-dashboard/app/ui/dashboard/sidenav.tsx:20:1]
 20 │             <NavLinks />
 21 │             <div className="hidden h-auto w-full grow rounded-md bg-gray-50 md:block"></div>
 22 │             <form
 23 │ ╭─▶           action={async () => {
 24 │ │               'use server';
 25 │ │               await signOut();
 26 │ ╰─▶           }}

Here is the entire sidenav.tsx implementation:
// app/ui/dashboard/sidenav.tsx

import Link from 'next/link';
import NavLinks from '@/app/ui/dashboard/nav-links';
import AcmeLogo from '@/app/ui/acme-logo';
import { PowerIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { signOut } from '@/auth';

export default function SideNav() {
  return (
    <div className="flex h-full flex-col px-3 py-4 md:px-2">
      <Link
        className="mb-2 flex h-20 items-end justify-start rounded-md bg-blue-600 p-4 md:h-40"
        href="/"
      >
        <div className="w-32 text-white md:w-40">
          <AcmeLogo />
        </div>
      </Link>
      <div className="flex grow flex-row justify-between space-x-2 md:flex-col md:space-x-0 md:space-y-2">
        <NavLinks />
        <div className="hidden h-auto w-full grow rounded-md bg-gray-50 md:block"></div>
        <form
          action={async () => {
            'use server';
            await signOut();
          }}
        >
          <button className="font-medium flex h-[48px] w-full grow items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-3 text-sm hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-blue-600 md:flex-none md:justify-start md:p-2 md:px-3">
            <PowerIcon className="w-6" />
            <div className="hidden md:block">Sign Out</div>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

I resolved this by moving the signout action to actions.ts file where we define server actions and set that to be the form's action.
// app/lib/actions.ts

export async function signout() {
  await signOut();
}

Was the original implementation in the tutorial not consistent with how Server Actions are handled in NextJS or did I miss something?

May not be a direct answer to this question, but can be helpful to anyone looking for a client side approach as I was.
"use client"

import { signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"
 
export default function SignIn() {
  return <button onClick={() => signIn("google")}>SignIn</button>
}

This snippet shows a sample for signIn(). Hope it helps.
